# How to force update CentOS from 7.5 to 7.7

Tags: linux, centos

I am trying to update to CentOS 7.7 from 7.5. I tried following all the tutorials (which essentially just said to run `yum update`) but I don't get the update. Here is some info:

```
➜  ~ sudo yum check-update            
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * elrepo: mirrors.coreix.net
 * epel: mirrors.coreix.net
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
➜  ~
```

And:

```
➜  ~ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core) 
➜  ~
```

Am I missing some repos? Or perhaps I need to force update it somehow?

UPDATE:

This is the content of my `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`:

```
[C7.5.1804-base]
name=CentOS-7.5.1804 - Base
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.5.1804/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
enabled=1

[C7.5.1804-updates]
name=CentOS-7.5.1804 - Updates
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.5.1804/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
enabled=1

[C7.5.1804-extras]
name=CentOS-7.5.1804 - Extras
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.5.1804/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
enabled=1

[C7.5.1804-centosplus]
name=CentOS-7.5.1804 - CentOSPlus
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.5.1804/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
enabled=1

[C7.5.1804-fasttrack]
name=CentOS-7.5.1804 - Fasttrack
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.5.1804/fasttrack/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
enabled=1
```

Does this means the version is hardcoded?

Comment: List all repo's : `yum repolist` .... Are you missing CentOS-Base.repo ? ... A "repo files package" : https://www.dropbox.com/s/xz19igzwcu3xn1d/yum-repofiles-CentOS7.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: @dawid: did you "cat /etc/redhat-release" first? Maybe "sudo yum clean all" before trying to upgrade.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Are you talking about this repo? `!C7.5.1804-base/x86_64       CentOS-7.5.1804 - Base`

Comment: @Didier The content of "/etc/redhat-release": `CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)`. No luck ater `sudo yum clean all`.

Comment: The repo files are identical for all versions. Unless you want an old update version of some or all packages : CentOS-Vault.repo. But no Vault repo's are enabled by default. The name of the default Base repo is `CentOS-Base.repo`.

Comment: Mmmm... There seems to be known issues that you may have already addressed, but then maybe not. Check the Know issues section there (https://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS7.1908), in case you need to edit your /etc/yum.conf with the suggested workaround.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Then, I don't have `CentOS-Base.repo`.

Comment: @Didier I set `gpgcheck=0` in `/etc/yum.conf`, run clean all and update and no luck.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Please see my update in the original post.

Comment: »»Does this means the version is hard coded«« : "baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.5.1804" is for old updates only. Please see my above comment about Vault. .... Update CentOS 7 : Add the default repo = CentOS-Base.repo etc. from my link.

Comment: I've never seen a hard-coded CentOS. It goes against the very essence of what IS CentOS, a community-developped and -maintained (with a little help from Red Had) server OS, so allowing and even encouraging fragmentation by refusing some hardware to upgrade would mean that users would turn their backs to CentOS after a while, and migrate their systems to other platforms. You didn't get any connection error message at all when trying to yum-update? You did do "yum clean-all", "yum upgrade" and "systemctl reboot", in sequence, all under "sudo"? EDIT: is this a physical machine or a virtual one?

Comment: @KnudLarsen On second thought, I might wait with it for a bit as it is not my machine and don't want to be in a position that I won't be able to work from home if something goes wrong.

Comment: @Didier I had no errors whatsoever. Perhaps this could have been hard-coded by IT as this is not my machine. Maybe it is to avoid potential issues when updating the system, as happened in the past. Especially now, since everyone is working from home.

Comment: OK got it. This is an actual PC with CentOS on it, or is it a physical, albeit distant server you're admin to, or is it a virtual server? If virtual, some hardware limitations on the host could explain why you can't upgrade.

Comment: @Didier This is a physical machine, a laptop, running CentOS natively on a partition.

Comment: OK, and I take it you have sudo rights, but not root, right? You go "su" in terminal, you get an error message?

Answer (score 1):

RHEL and CentOS releases are Rolling Updates. Any 7.x "Point Release" will upgrade to the Latest Version, currently 7.9.

There are few Good Reasons to Freeze your release at a specific point. Make sure you have one. If so, just replace 7.5.1804 with 7.7.1908. If not, just use the standard Centos-*.repo files.